# Compile time floating point division by zero in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, language-lawyer, constexpr

It is well known, if one divides a floating-point number on zero in run-time then the result will be either infinity or not-a-number (the latter case if the dividend was also zero). But is it allowed to divide by zero in C++ `constexpr` expressions (in compile time), e.g.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double x = 0.;
    // run-time division: all compilers print "-nan"
    std::cout << 0./x << std::endl; 

    // compile-time division, diverging results
    constexpr double y = 0.;
    std::cout << 0./y << std::endl;
}
```

In this program the first printed number is obtained from division in run-time, and all compilers are pretty consistent in printing `-nan`. (Side question: why not `+nan`?)

But in second case the compilers diverge. MSVC simply stops compilation with the error:

```
error C2124: divide or mod by zero
```

GCC still prints `-nan`, while Clang changes the sign printing “positive” `nan`, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/eP744er8n

Does the language standard permit all three behaviors of the compilers for compile-time division: 1) reject the program, 2) produce the same division result as in run-time, 3) produce a different (in sign bit) result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Division by zero is undefined behavior. (So anything goes)

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf
Section 8.5.5, point 4

Comment: fyi direct link into the current draft [\[expr.mul\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.mul)

Comment: I am really surprised that C++ standard contradicts IEEE 754 standard, where division on zero is a well defined operation.

Comment: @RichardCritten ty

Comment: And yes its a bit strange, but the standard talks about dividing expressions. Which also covers among others other numerical types not just floating point numbers.

Comment: @Fedor  IEEE 754 is not required by the standard - _"...The value representation of floating-point types is implementation-defined...."_ [\[basic.fundamental\].12](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#12)

Comment: @Fedor: Specifying division by zero is undefined behavior is not a contradiction of IEEE-754. If one document defines X and another document does not define X, then there is one definition of X with no conflict, not two definitions of X that differ.

Comment: As far as I understand, *undefined behavior* means that any behavior is allowed and not that the behavior is fixed by another standard. So if a compiler simply ignores divide by zero operations in C++ code, it will be still a valid compiler behavior according to C++ standard, which hopefully no compiler does.