Why is floating-point zero-divide forbidden in a constexpr?
Using the g++ compiler, both of these compile fine:
constexpr double d1 = 2.0 / 1.0;
const double d2 = 2.0 / 0.0;

But this does not:
constexpr double d2 = 2.0 / 0.0;

The compile-time error is:
error: ‘(2.0e+0 / 0.0)’ is not a constant expression

Note that cppreference gives this exact example, confirming that it's not allowed.
I don't understand why it's not allowed.  Keeping in mind that std::numeric_limits::is_iec559 is constexpr, the compiler clearly knows at compile time, within a constexpr, whether divide-by-zero is allowed.  So, in the case that it is allowed... why isn't it allowed within the constexpr?
EDIT: It was suggested that this question is siimilar to The behaviour of floating point division by zero .  My question here is intended to be more focused (why do the first two expressions appear to be allowed, but the third disallowed)?   The answers to the other question don't seem to shed light on that: some of the answers seem to imply all three expressions are UB (and therefore are disallowed? I don't think I believe that; but in any case there's something specific about constexpr that seems to make a difference, thus this question which is focused on the constexpr).
This question is also similar to Compile time floating point division by zero in C++ whose accepted answer (essentially "it's UB so anything goes") doesn't help at all.

Division by zero is undefined behaviour in C++, even if your compiler uses IEEE754 which defines such behaviour.

@Yksisarvinen no, it's no longer (necessarily) UB; in fact it's almost never UB.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926763/the-behaviour-of-floating-point-division-by-zero/42927051#answer-78690896

I can't say what cppreference meant by that, but C++ standard explicitly says it's undefined behaviour, no conditions. http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.mul#4. And UB is not allowed in constant expressions.

@DonHatch the linked answer refers to the C documentation https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic .  I guess this is a place where C++ and C diverge.

@Yksisarvinen Interesting.  I was assuming cppreference was correctly summarizing from a recent (more recent than c++11) version of the c++ spec.  Perhaps not?  Or perhaps it's referring to some other section.  Now I'm back to being very confused.

@DonHatch As noticed by Richard, you found a page for C language. C++ page says "If rhs is zero, the behavior is undefined" - and then it proceeds to explain the behaviour of division by zero if std::numeric_limits::is_iec559 is true... I'm not sure what is the rule as intended here, but rule as written, your compiler is correct to reject division by zero in constexpr.

@RichardCritten ah I see, thanks.  I think the correct page for c++ is https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Built-in_multiplicative_operators .  And I think that's what the other cppreference page I quoted is paraphrasing.  Except that I'm probably using terms incorrectly and I need to adjust my thinking: "sometimes UB" is actually the same as "UB"  as pointed out by recent comments on my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926763/the-behaviour-of-floating-point-division-by-zero/78690896?noredirect=1#answer-78690896 (and "UB" isn't always alarming).

Also: "7.7 Constant expressions... 5 An expression E is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of E, following the rules of the abstract
machine (6.9.1), would evaluate one of the following:... (5.7) — an operation that would have undefined behavior as specified in Clause 4 through Clause 15 of this
document [Note: including, for example, signed integer overflow (7.2), certain pointer arithmetic (7.6.6),
division by zero (7.6.5), or certain shift operations (7.6.7) —end note] ;"
Quite explicit

This question is similar to: The behaviour of floating point division by zero. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

cppreference seems also a bit optimist with IEEE 754: from this standard:
7.3 Division by zero 7.3.0
The divideByZero exception shall be signaled if and only if an exact infinite result is defined for an
operation on finite operands. The default result of divideByZero shall be an ∞ correctly signed according to
the operation:
― For division, when the divisor is zero and the dividend is a finite non-zero number, the sign of the
infinity is the exclusive OR of the operands’ signs (see 6.3)...
I don't fully understand the implication. 0/0 is not mentioned there

@Oersted regarding the difference from the other question:  I made an "EDIT:" attempting to explain.  Hope it made some sense.

Indeed for the first suggested dupe, but also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30459773/floating-point-division-by-zero-not-constexpr, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68970223/compile-time-floating-point-division-by-zero-in-c?

@Oersted Ah I see.  Yes, it looks like the same question.  But the accepted answer to that one doesn't help clarify much, for me.  On the other hand, the discussion in this comment thread here is beginning to help me understand, I think.  Not sure how to proceed forward.  Maybe if I get enough clariity I (or someone) can write up a clear and complete answer to the other one, and mark this one as a dup?

Another way to see the "issue": https://godbolt.org/z/7q6x3Y45E. It's the constant evaluation context that, rightfully, triggers a compilation error. In my snippet, the first line (not constant evaluated) compiles but is still formally UB I think.

@DonHatch: this seems the right way to go. My understanding is that div by zero is UB, period. IEEE754 only specify finite (!= 0)/0 but not 0/0. Probably debatable, but my conclusion so far would be 1- compilers behaviors seem compliant with the standard; 2- cppref wording is wrong; 3- to never rely on /0 in my code.

btw: https://godbolt.org/z/747abWT7z gcc and clang are processing 0/0 differently (-nan and nan)

Regarding cppreference page provided earlier, if floating point follows IEEE 754, division by zero raises either FE_INVALID or FE_DIVBYZERO. If math_errhandling has MATH_ERREXCEPT set, that raises floating point exception. Exceptions are not allowed in constexpr. If math_errhandling has MATH_ERREXCEPT set to 0, then there's no exceptions and a bug report can be filed.

@Red.Wave Oh!  All right, I think you've hit on the one explanation anyone has mentioned that is actually compelling to me (unlike any of the previous arguments of the form "it's disallowed because of the following inscrutible unmotivated and possibly outdated passages in the c++ spec whose contents I can't even read and have to guess from what cppreference says").  So, this convincing to me: even though the compiler does know IEEE754 is supported, the compiler really can't just evaluate 1/0 to be +infinity, because that might not actually be the answer, depending on runtime settings.

math_errhandling is macro that expands to core constant integer value. I mean if this compile time constant has MATH_ERREXCEPT then we know at compile-time, that floating point division by .0 is throwing/raising. Otherwise we know it won't do exceptions. So, in the former case, compiler should not accept division by .0 at compile-time, while in the latter case it should. Otherwise the compiler is misbehaving. Moreover, interestingly the case for operands of different types is not specified in cppreference; so I refrain from simple term div by 0.

@Red.Wave But https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/math_errhandling says "If the implementation supports IEEE floating-point arithmetic (IEC 60559), math_errhandling & MATH_ERREXCEPT is required to be non-zero." This makes me think MATH_ERREXCEPT, i.e. "indicates that floating-point exceptions are used" doesn't mean quite what you describe above? Perhaps, at the level of this doc, 1./0. always throws FE_DIVBYZERO, then it's up to the runtime (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv) to decide whether whether to turn that into something else (infinity or abort) at higher level?

(that is... assuming IEEE754 is supported)

@DonHatch Whatever exception means is abnormal termination of program. And that cannot happen during compilation. That basically means division by 0 can not be constexpr. I had originally missed the paragraph that you pointed out. Thanks for the note.

This question is similar to: Compile time floating point division by zero in C++. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Fedor I added an edit.  This question isn't really different from that one, but (as often happens) that other one has an accepted answer that doesn't resolve anything at all, in my perception, so it seems the potential for getting anything useful from that one has stalled.  In contrast, this current question is generating discussion and and answer which (along with current/recent discussion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926763/the-behaviour-of-floating-point-division-by-zero/78690896#comment138739515_78690896) are actually helping me understand.

The ISO C++ standard explicitly specifies that division by zero has undefined behavior, for both integral and floating point types.
See [expr.mul]/4.
If evaluation of an expression would have undefined behavior according to the core language specification, then an expression whose evaluation would involve that evaluation, is specified to not be a (core) constant expression.
Therefore any division by zero must be impossible at compile-time.
Although division by zero is undefined per C++ standard, typically implementations of floating point types adhere to IEEE 754, which defines the result of dividing by zero. That's of course fine. If a program has undefined behavior according to the C++ standard, then the compiler is free to give it any semantic. In particular it can promise to adhere to stricter rules, e.g. another specification.
However, inside constant expressions the language is intentionally restricted to what is explicitly defined by the standard. Compilers can't extent the behavior of constexpr as they can at runtime. If a constexpr variable's initialization is not a constant expression, then the program is ill-formed.
Although, the standard never requires a compiler to fail compilation. If the program is ill-formed, then the only requirement is that the compiler shall emit one diagnostic. This could just as well be just a warning and then the compiler could simply perform the division at compile-time in the same way that it would at runtime.
In certain contexts, rather than just well-formedness, the semantics of the program can be affected by whether or not an expression is a constant expression. In that case, the compiler is required to give the program the correct semantics. A warning and different behavior wouldn't be possible in that case.

The fact that it’s not a constant expression could be utilized by a well-formed program for SFINAE.  A conforming compiler could allow it with a warning otherwise (GCC does this for certain conversions that are formally narrowing but obviously safe), but that sort of inconsistency can be scary.

"That's of course fine."  :-)  That's actually a crucial point, and not a universally understood one at all.  The common (wrong) understanding seems to be that it is in fact not fine-- that is, that UB means a conforming compiler cannot guarantee a stricter specification. Thus lot of conversations about UB end prematurely with "it's UB so anything goes" which is spectacularly unhelpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68970223/compile-time-floating-point-division-by-zero-in-c#answer-68970272  Thanks for the more nuanced explanation; accepting.
